How can I limit the rows in tanstack table?
How can I limit the rows being shown in my tanstack query table? It has a default value of 10, is it possible to limit it for only 5? What I accomplish it, I make the selected values limit to [5,10,20,30,40,], but it didn't change the default value of rows.
admin-data-table.tsx
 <div className="rounded-md border">
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>

        <div className="flex items-center justify-end space-x-2 py-4">
          <DataTablePagination table={table} />
        </div>
      </div>

admin-data-table-pagination.tsx
import {
    ChevronLeftIcon,
    ChevronRightIcon,
    DoubleArrowLeftIcon,
    DoubleArrowRightIcon,
  } from "@radix-ui/react-icons"
  import { Table } from "@tanstack/react-table"
  
  import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
  import {
    
    Select,
    SelectContent,
    SelectItem,
    SelectTrigger,
    SelectValue,
  } from "@/components/ui/select"
  
  interface DataTablePaginationProps<TData> {
    table: Table<TData>
  }
  
  export function DataTablePagination<TData>({
    table,
  }: DataTablePaginationProps<TData>) {
    return (
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between px-2">
        <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
          {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
        </div>
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-6 lg:space-x-8">
          <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
            <p className="text-sm font-medium">Rows per page</p>
            <Select
              value={`${table.getState().pagination.pageSize}`}
              onValueChange={(value) => {
                table.setPageSize(Number(value))
              }}
            >
              <SelectTrigger className="h-8 w-[70px]">
                <SelectValue placeholder={table.getState().pagination.pageSize} />
              </SelectTrigger>
              <SelectContent side="top">
                {[5, 10, 20, 30, 40].map((pageSize) => (
                  <SelectItem key={pageSize} value={`${pageSize}`}>
                    {pageSize}
                  </SelectItem>
                ))}
              </SelectContent>
            </Select>
          </div>
          <div className="flex w-[100px] items-center justify-center text-sm font-medium">
            Page {table.getState().pagination.pageIndex + 1} of{" "}
            {table.getPageCount()}
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              className="hidden h-8 w-8 p-0 lg:flex"
              onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(0)}
              disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Go to first page</span>
              <DoubleArrowLeftIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              className="h-8 w-8 p-0"
              onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
              disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Go to previous page</span>
              <ChevronLeftIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              className="h-8 w-8 p-0"
              onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
              disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Go to next page</span>
              <ChevronRightIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="outline"
              className="hidden h-8 w-8 p-0 lg:flex"
              onClick={() => table.setPageIndex(table.getPageCount() - 1)}
              disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
            >
              <span className="sr-only">Go to last page</span>
              <DoubleArrowRightIcon className="h-4 w-4" />
            </Button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  

